# How could a Netty server send data to different clients?

Tags: java, netty

I wanna make something like a simple chat.
Server have to add new clients in a list of clients, and when one client sends message to the server, server have to resend this message to the other clients.
I know, how to read message from client, but I don't know, how to send message from server to the client. And i don't sure where should be list of clients, but guess that in handler class.
Here is my main class which initializes the server class

```
package firstPackage;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    Server server = new Server(9050);
    server.run();
    }
}
```

Here is the Server class

```
package firstPackage;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel;

import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;


public class Server {

private int port;

public Server(int port)
{
    this.port=port;
}

public void run() throws Exception
{
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try{
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(bossGroup,workerGroup)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
             @Override
             public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception{
                 ch.pipeline().addLast(new DiscardServerHandler());
             }
         })
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG,128)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        ChannelFuture f = b.bind(port).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }
    finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}

}
```

And here the Handler class

```
package firstPackage;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;
import io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil;

public class DiscardServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    try {
        while (in.isReadable()) {
            System.out.print((char) in.readByte());
            System.out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println();

        ctx.writeAndFlush("hey"); // вот здесь я думал, что сообщение будет отправлятся клиенту, от которого я получил сообщение, но не отправляется

    } finally {
        ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
    }
}

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("channel is active");
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("channel is invactive");
}

@Override
public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("handler added");
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

Actually now I have not list of clients, because i even don't know what type of object this list must contain, in C# it's was Socket object, so what in Netty?

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsz-assb1X8) should help you out (it's a YouTube video, so spare the comments about broken links please). In particular, it uses a [ChannelGroup](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) to solve the problem of which you ask. And, yes, it goes in the handler on the server side.

Edit:

Notice too that in the example the `ChannelGroup` is static. I might argue it would be better to not use a static member and inject a `ChannelGroup` into the handler from the server class, but the simplicity of the static member may be preferable if you just want to get something working quickly.